# How to make an absolute positioned element align center when it needs to be 50% of window

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to make a banner that is 50% of the width of the "content wrapper" and that content wrapper is dynamically sized to a max width (so it can be, in theory, 0px-1330px). The content wrapper is the dark gray box here. It contains the content of the site. Within that content is a banner that comes out from the side of window. The window in this exactly has a boundary of the black outline.

How with HTML/CSS can I make the content of the purple container fit within the dark "content wrapper" even tho it is 50% of the window and the content lines up with left side of the wrapper when I don't know the specific width.

I've tried all kinds of math but I can't quite get it. I'm using CSS `var`s for the site max width and I can use `var` or `calc` to make this work but just no combo is working.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this fit your question?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
.banner {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #a0f;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.banner::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #a0f;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(100% - 50vw);
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(50vw - 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Content Wrapper</h1>
    <div class="banner-wrap">
        <div class="banner">
            <h2>The title here</h2>
            <p>Some other text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that's it! Dang, I spent hours and hours on this!

Comment: That calculation part is superb ! Never would have thought something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.window {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px black solid;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 75%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  padding:20px 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
}
p{
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
  color:white;
}

.banner-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  clip-path:inset( -100vw 0vw -100vw -100vw );
}

.banner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -50vw;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p><b>Some text here</b></p>
      <p>Some text here</p>
      <div class="banner-container">
        <div class="banner">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```